# Assertion failure error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

```
username=@"sri";
CalendarViewController *calendarViewController=[[CalendarViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CalendarViewController" bundle:nil AndUserName:username];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:calendarViewController animated:YES];
```

> Assertion failure in -[UITextFieldLabel setTextColor:],
>   /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UILabel.m:314 2012-12-11
>   11:00:59.257 TIMESHEET_MANAGER[553:207] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
>   'Invalid parameter not satisfying: color'

*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: paste code of setTextColor

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a `setTextColor` method in your class. It is expecting a `UIColor` object but something else is passed to that method. Check it and correct that. That should resolve this.